What is the ideal way to push updates from a helper util class, like a LoginUtil.kt, to the ViewModel and the UI itself subsequently?
I am trying to make a LoginUtil.kt class in my Android App. In short, the class is supposed to be a simpler high-level interface for the ViewModel to interact with to log in and log out within the app.
However, the problem I'm facing is that I don't know which API to use for pushing updates whenever a login or logout happens. I have a FirebaseUser object within the LoginUtil class which will be null whenever the user calls login or logout but the problem is I want the ViewModel to observe this FirebaseUser object.
I have tried using flow but it requires that I use an infinite while loop or repeat function to keep pushing updates at intervals.
StateFlow also came to mind but I am sure StateFlow should not be used here due to UserUtil not being a ViewModel subclass.

You'll want to use a Flow.


I want the ViewModel to observe this FirebaseUser object.

A FirebaseUser object is not an object that can be observed. If you want to track the user auth state, I recommend you use FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener. As you probably see onAuthStateChanged method:

This method gets invoked in the UI thread on changes in the authentication state.

Regarding the way of listening to the auth state in Kotlin:

I have tried using flow but it requires that I use an infinite while loop or repeat function to keep pushing updates at intervals.

I personally prefer callbackFlow for such operations. If you want you can also check how I implemented it in a public repository.

Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Hey sorry, i never got an email from stack overflow about your answer until I opened it again today. I didn't try it tho because I changed my app's architecture quite a bit and I don't need to observe anything anymore.
